# How to remove this brass collar from the pipe

Tags: faucet, bathtub

The bathtub faucet is leaking at the diverter so the water can't be directed to the shower head. I bought a universal replacement (different brand) and attempted to remove the old one (it was a [Delta MAINTSP831CH](https://hdsupplysolutions.com/shop/p/delta-chrome-universal-tub-spout-p425015)). After finally removing the small hex screw at the underside of the brass collar, I can't get the collar off the pipe. I applied some lubricant and tried pulling it off, but it wouldn't come off. I then pushed the collar further in to see if there's anything blocking it, only to discover a notch on the pipe which is probably preventing the collar from coming off.

I've replace a few faucets/spout before and even after reviewing the instructions for Delta faucet and the universal one, none mentioned the case with this notched pipe; All the pipes I've encountered are straight and smooth. Has anyone seen this before? Could anyone offer insight into why this pipe is notched and how to get the brass collar off?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried working it back and forth with a pair of pliers while pulling? If it has been there a long time it may take some persuading.

Comment: Yeah, I used pliers and turned it back and forth while pulling. It turns very easily after I applied lubricant to it, but it just seem to be stuck at that point in the pipe at the notch. If you see closely I think the outer diameter of the pipe changes after the notch, which is what baffles me.

Comment: They may have soldered it at that spot and then drove the collar over it. You may have to cut it off. 

Comment: The notch really does not look like a notch, it looks like a pipe was soldered over the pipe that the brass piece is on. One side of the proposed notch does not look the same diameter as the other side of the notch. This may either be the same thing @ArchonOSX was referring to but I think it is a slightly different take... It can be confirmed by carefully sliding a wire with a slightly bent tip to ride down the inside diameter of the pipe and "see" if the inside has a ledge as in riding up on a new, smaller diameter or it drops back down to the same approximate size as before.

Comment: Thanks, looks like those are the only possible explanation and I'll have to cut the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Heat the brass collar with a propane torch. Insulate the tile and block the wall opening with heat proof material. Then twist (gently) while hot.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you loosen that Allen screw? It could be that the Allen screw was designed to engage the groove and so lock the tube in place.

Alternatively, perhaps the groove in the tube was designed to receive an O-ring.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though that's what I thought at first as well. However, if you look at the last pic I was finally able to remove the set screw with an Allen wrench but still was unable to twist the collar off. It turns out that it wasn't a groove/notch but an edge of a joint as Archon and Jack suggested.